# CSS3 Webkit-filter Property

Tags: php, html, css, filter, webkit

I have got an image that has got plain red color, #FF0000. My target is to change it to #1100FF.

Just couple of weeks ago I get to know that we have tinting/filtering capability in CSS3. It works pretty good however final color of the Image is not #1100FF. I check color through Chrome Tool 'Awesome Color Picker'

So how I do it is what you must be asking.

```
function RGB_TO_HSV($R, $G, $B)    // RGB values:    0-255, 0-255, 0-255
                    {                                // HSV values:    0-360, 0-100, 0-100
                        $HSL = array();
                        // Convert the RGB byte-values to percentages
                        $R = ($R / 255);
                        $G = ($G / 255);
                        $B = ($B / 255);

                        $maxRGB = max($R, $G, $B);
                        $minRGB = min($R, $G, $B);
                        $chroma = $maxRGB - $minRGB;

                        $computedV = 100 * $maxRGB;

                        if ($chroma == 0)
                        {
                            $HSL['H']= "0deg";
                            $HSL['S']= "0%";
                            $HSL['V']= (3*$computedV)."%";
                            return $HSL;
                        }
                        $computedS = 100 * ($chroma / $maxRGB);

                        if ($R == $minRGB)
                            $h = 3 - (($G - $B) / $chroma);
                        elseif ($B == $minRGB)
                            $h = 1 - (($R - $G) / $chroma);
                        else // $G == $minRGB
                            $h = 5 - (($B - $R) / $chroma);

                        $computedH = 60 * $h;
                        $HSL['H'] = $computedH."deg";
                        $HSL['S'] = $computedS."%";
                        $HSL['V'] = $computedV."%";

                        return $HSL;
                    }
```

Then In CSS, I do this:

```
img {-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(<?=$HSL['H']?>) saturate(<?=$HSL['S']?>) brightness(<?=$HSL['V']?>);}
```

Now please tell me how I can achieve the required color? Do I need to add or subtract the original color (ie. #FF0000) to get the desired color or the code I am using is not correct or what?

Output Color is : #0F2DFF

Edit: There is no restriction that color of the image is #FF0000. I can change it as long as I can tint the image to the any color accurately.

Comment: Would love the answer to this..never knew this could be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Joram. It is not working as expected.

My best friend was CSS shapes techniques. I made shapes in the css and color it to whatever I liked and it was pixel perfect. Though it take some time but it was worth it and lot effective than wasting time on filtering techniques.

I am tired of half-baked standards. : (

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a webkit or css bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=237524
or at least the [mathematical transformation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement) behind it is not as straightforward as directly shifting the hue.
This can easily be observed in this example:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; color:#333; background-color: hsl(100,100%,50%)">Original</div>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; color:#333; background-color: hsl(200,100%,50%)">Expected</div>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; color:#333; background-color: hsl(100,100%,50%); -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(100deg);">Filtered</div>
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8jEe/1/)

So I don't think it is possible yet to trasform precisely one color to another without some crazy  reverse engineering of the webkit algorithm.