# Effective way to filter an Image

Tags: php, css, filter

What is the effective way for tinting an image that has got transparent background?

Is it PHP ImageFilter ?
Is it CSS Filter ?
Is it Jquery ?

I have tried PHP Image Filter but that doesn't look to be good programming. Other is CSS Filter, It is newer standard and I liked the idea but can't get to work it as effect. Check my other question.

Need help solving it!

Thanks

Added the link to the other question: [CSS3 Webkit-filter Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221037/css3-webkit-filter-property)

Comment: Maybe link to your other question?

Comment: Added a link A.S. Roma. Thanks!